# Setting the input shape while training using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a dataset using keras having `xtrain.shape ---> (2040, 2, 5000)` and `ytrain.shape ---> (2040,)` (Real Data). Sample miniaturized `xtrain` and `ytrain` data is like

**xtrain**

```
array([[[ 2,  2,  7,  1,  5],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  3]],

       [[ 5,  0,  3,  1,  6],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  6]],

       [[ 2,  9,  8,  8,  7],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12,  2]],

       [[ 5,  7,  7,  6,  8],
        [13, 14, 15, 16,  1]]])
```

**ytrain**

```
array([0,1,2,3])
```

When I tried to build a network model using

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

input_shape = (2,5000)
no_classes = 7
loss_function = sparse_categorical_crossentropy
no_epochs = 100
optimizer = Adam()
validation_split = 0.2
verbosity = 1

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(no_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss=loss_function,
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy']) 
# Fit data to model
history = model.fit(input_train, target_train,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            epochs=no_epochs,
            verbose=verbosity,
            validation_split=validation_split)
```

getting the following error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 2, 5000)
```

I am confused about setting the input shape during creation of the network. Is this due to the shape of input ?

Comment: Have you thought how exactly Conv2D should interpret your data? And why it expects 4D inputs?

Comment: Does this mean i have to reshape the training data ? xtrain.ndim gives 3. so its a 3D data. yeah why it expects 4D. its weird

Comment: The documentation clearly shows why 4D data is needed: https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your train set must be, for example (2040, 64, 64, 3). And the input_shape = (64, 64, 3)

Comment: My training data shape is (2040, 2, 5000), so i gave input shape (2,5000) which throws the error :(

Comment: Are you using `cifar10` dataset ?

Comment: No. I am creating the dataset from from different audio wav files. In  [[ 2,  2,  7,  1,  5],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  3]] ,---> [ 2,  2,  7,  1,  5] will be data from one file and [1,2,3,4,3] is data from another file. I had to choose like that. Its another story :(

Comment: I just saw the import from cifar. it was a mistake. I edited that

Comment: Use 1D convolution layers for audio files.